# Is there a word for when people secretly want to fail at something they're doing?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I'm looking for a word (or possibly a phrase) to describe a situation where someone, usually in secret, wants to fail at something they're doing, or where one or more people want a project that they're part of to fail.

Some examples:

- A player is repeatedly not picked for his team's basketball games. After a while, he becomes frustrated and starts hoping that his team lose matches, as it may increase the chances of his coach making a change and giving him a chance.
- A software development team is given a difficult project with a very short timeframe. It requires long hours of hard work. Some members of the team want  the project to miss its deadline in order to show management they've been overworked.
- A kid is always chosen by her friends to be the goalkeeper when they play football. She hates playing in goals, so starts messing up saves, dropping the ball and such, so they'll pick someone else and let her play outfield.

I was thinking something along the lines of "schadenfreude" (those Germans have a word for everything!) as they're taking a degree of pleasure from something unpleasant, but it doesn't quite fit, as it's their own endeavour and they should, ostensibly, want themselves or their teams to succeed.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on whether they are conscious of it or not. When you say secretly, do you mean they know it or not? Usually, it's called being or acting masochistic.

Comment: @Hot Licks Only if they know they will do it badly and like that.

Comment: By secretly, I just mean that they keep it to themselves. Masochistic sort of works but it's maybe a little extreme for the situation - it's not so much that they derive pleasure directly from failure as that they harbour a desire for it that seems at odds with what you'd expect. They might want to fail in order to highlight a problem or enact change.

Comment: *Subterfuge* would be a good choice in some contexts although it is not specific to self-sabotage as the sole strategy.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subterfuge - has a lot of synonyms and other ideas

Comment: @HotLicks "I'm so sorry that our clothes are all grey again. I guess I'm just not good at this laundry thing."

Comment: I've heard the term "self-sabotage"  but I don't think it is exactly what you are getting at.. and these psychological definitions get squishy anyway. https://www.psychologytoday.com/basics/self-sabotage

Comment: If you are meaning more deliberate, you could start with words like "ploy" or "ruse" ... and maybe couple it "incompetence" :  "ruse of incompetence"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - these terms are quite useful for when someone is playing an active or underhanded role in bringing about a failure, but I guess the part I was really hoping to get a word for was more the desire or hope for something you're a part of to fail, as opposed any role you might play in making that happen. Apologies if my description was too broad.

Comment: I call this *making a point* - as in "tact is the art of making a point without making an enemy."

Comment: +1 on the question.  I added the tag "phrases" because you said a phrase would be a possibility.  Just delete the added tag if you don't want it.

Comment: Sounds like throwing a fight.

Comment: "Rooting for failure" is maybe right. I don't know if there's an established phrase that explicitly states that the desire is secret. I imagine that context usually makes it abundantly clear whether the desire must be kept secret. For deliberately doing a bad job in furtherance of that desire, you can often prefix the virtuous verb with "mal-", e.g. maladministration.

Answer (score 4):

***Tanking*** is a common term in sports to refer to purposefully losing.

> Tanking ... the act of giving up a match or "throwing it away", losing intentionally or not competing. ([Urban
>   Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tanking))

e.g.  They *tanked* their match because they got angry with the umpire.

This practice is common in the NFL and other professional sports where losing more often means you'll be able to get a better draft position in the following year.  Professional sports leagues benefit from parity so leagues like to give certain advantages to poor teams and disadvantages to successfully teams in hopes that no one team does terribly for long periods of time.

Just last month, an ESPN sportswriter posted an article about the advantages and disadvantages of tanking, *[A tanking guide to the NFL, and a warning](http://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/19652764/tanking-nfl-advantages-disadvantages-worth-new-york-jets-cleveland-browns-2017)*

There is a certain stigma attached to purposefully losing so most teams won't admit the practice, but it is nonetheless common because of the big advantage it can give to the franchise.

Comment: Good suggestions, tanking or throwing a game is close to the heart of the matter - I've seen similar stuff in football/soccer, where managers field weakened teams in some games, or even sometimes where players seem to perform poorly to force a change of coach (see: Chelsea in 2016 or Leicester in 2017). I was hoping to find a single word or phrase that encapsulates the _desire_ to fail or lose though, rather than the act itself. Maybe there isn't one just for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also call it ***feigning incompetence***.

Here is an article about what to do when kids try to do it:  [How do you handle feigned incompetence in your children](http://forums.welltrainedmind.com/topic/500511-how-do-you-handle-feigned-incompetence-in-your-children/).

> Mom:  Can you please wash the dishes for me?
>
> Child:  Oops! I dropped another dish. I don't think I can handle this, Mom!

Answer (score 1):

In your first two examples, there's merely a *desire* for failure.
In the third example, the subject takes action.

For third case, you can use a word like ***undermine*** or ***sabotage***.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a word for such a thing is unnecessary. If you want to convey that someone secretly wants to fail at their task, then it ought to be done so secretly, i.e. through implication. Phrases such as "he/she was/felt dubious/uneasy/antagonistic/unwilling about doing X" are excellent at hinting towards such inner desires.